# por que no puedo leer un archivo xml en python con pandas

Tags: python, xml

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a entender mejor como se lee un archivo xml en ptyhon de manera optima

Comment: Que tal esto ? https://pypi.org/project/pandas-read-xml/ Espero que te ayude

Comment: Hola, aunque esta pregunta es sobre programación, tal y como está redactada ahora mismo, es demasiado amplia y necesita detalles y aclaraciones para poder ayudarte. Por favor, comparte lo que has intentado y los errores o dificultades que estés encontrando. Lee [ask] y dale a [edit] para añadir más información y que la pregunta pueda ser reabierta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar el módulo [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) de Python. Copiando el XML de la página de la documentación:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>"""

raiz = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
```

Ahora `raiz` está apuntando al elemento `<data>`, el primero del XML. Puedes obtener el nombre de la etiqueta con `raiz.tag`, sus atributos con `raiz.attrib`, y puedes iterar por sus hijos con `for hijo in raid:`, o directamente con accesos al array. Con `raiz.text` podrías ver el contenido del elemento.

```
print(raiz.tag, raiz.attrib)
for hijo in raiz:
    print(hijo.tag, "es hijo de", raiz.tag, "y tiene atributos:", hijo.attrib)
    for nieto in hijo:
        print(nieto.tag, "es hijo de", hijo.tag, "y tiene atributos:", nieto.attrib)
        print("Contenido del nieto:", nieto.text)
```

Comment: Hola ArianJM, no todas las preguntas se pueden o se deben contestar. Ahórrate un poco de frustración y evita responder a preguntas que son inciertas o deficientes en detalles específicos que puedan identificar el problema real. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro aunque tienes razón en que la pregunta es muy poco detallada. La pregunta de "¿Cómo leer un XML en Python?" me bastante concreta y sencilla de contestar. Similar a "¿Cómo leer un JSON en Javascript?" Por eso la contesté.